# Thunderbird: Unable to add email account

Tags: thunderbird

After installing Thunderbird v32.2 (for the first time ever), I tried to add email account using Account Settings -> Add Mail Account.

However, the wizard does not come up. No error messages, nothing in the System Event logs basically nothing happens.

I have Windows 8 64 bit laptop and noticed that Thunderbird is 32 bit app. Is that an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably seeing [bug 1107902](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1107902).

To get it working, follow the instructions from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1015941#answer-660970:

Run this within PowerShell in the context of the affected user account:

Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM -Name ColorizationColor -Type DWord -Value 3297742735 -Verbose

OR (the hard way):

1. List item
2. Open the Control Panel
3. Open "Color and Appearance"

   - In Category View, this is under "Appearance and Personalization » Personalization » Change the color of your taskbar and window borders"
   - in Icon views, this is under "Personalization » Color"
4. Select a color
5. Save Changes

Comment: I tried the option of "Control Panel" and it totally worked!